# How to parse Json Two-dimensional array in Extjs 6.5.2?

Tags: extjs

I want to get all values in a Two-dimensional array and I'm sure I'm doing something in my model config. How can I do that?

Here's the code for my store:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.PathStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.PathStore',
storeId:'PathStore',
model : 'Test.model.PathModel',
autoSync:true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url:"url",
    method:'GET',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty : ''
    }
}
});
```

Here's the code for my model:

```
Ext.define('Test.model.PathModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {name:'CID', type:'auto'},
    {name:'NAME', type:'auto'},
    {name:'DEFAULT_NAME', type:'auto'},
    {name:'REPRESENTATIONS', type:'auto'}
    ]
});
```

Here's the code for my controller:

```
onButtonClick: function (selModel, record, index, options) {

    var pathStore = Ext.getStore('PathStore');
    pathStore.load({
        // Some params,
        callback: function(records, success, response, options) {
            if(success){
            var arr = Object.values(records[0].getData().DEFAULT_NAME);
            console.log(records);
            console.log(arr);
            console.log(records[0].getData());
          //Something  I Have To Do 
            }
}
scope: this
});
}
```

Here's the format for my Json:

```html
[
  [
  {
      "CID": 111111,
      "NAME": null,
      "DEFAULT_NAME": "Hello guys",
      "REPRESENTATIONS": null,
      "ALL_REPRESENTATIONS": [
        {
          "cid": 111111,
          "Name": "Hello",
          "DefaultName": "guys",
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "CID": 2222222,
      "NAME": null,
      "DEFAULT_NAME": "Hello World",
      "REPRESENTATIONS": null,
      "ALL_REPRESENTATIONS": [
        {
          "cid": 22222222,
          "Name": "Hello",
          "DefaultName": "World",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

[Json Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYIHS.png)

I get [object Object] or something else in `DEFAULT_NAME`, `NAME` and `CID`. How can I do for this?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: The code you gave above shows, your PathStore points to model Test.model.PathModel where as your model name is Test.model.Representation.

Comment: Other than that, if the fields DEFAULT_NAME, NAME and CID return int or string data then you should set the respective type in the model instead of auto for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the data from the nested array is to use the reader's [transform](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#cfg-transform) configuration.

> It is passed the raw (deserialized) data object. The transform
>   function returns a data object, which can be a modified version of the
>   original data object, or a completely new data object.

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: '',
    transform: function(data) {
        return Ext.Array.map(data, function(nestedDataArray) {
           return nestedDataArray[0];
        });
    }
}
```

This way you get rid of the enclosing array and normalize the data.

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25ut

Answer (score 0):

If you have One-To-Many relaition in your model, use 'hasMany' property in model config:

```
Ext.define("Test.model.RepresentationModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'cid', 'Name', 'DefaultName'
    ],
    belongsTo: 'Test.model.PathModel'
});

Ext.define('Test.model.PathModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {name:'CID', type:'auto'},
        {name:'NAME', type:'auto'},
        {name:'DEFAULT_NAME', type:'auto'},
        {name:'REPRESENTATIONS', type:'auto'}
    ],

    hasMany: {model: 'Test.model.RepresentationModel', name: 'ALL_REPRESENTATIONS'},
});
```

Comment: Which part fixes the problem? Please elaborate.